# Construction of special set of $6$ points

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials, geometric-construction

Construct a set $A\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ with $|A|=6$ such that for all $f\in \mathbb{R}[x,y]$ with $\deg(f)\leq 2$ then $|A\cap V(f)|\leq 5$
Where $V(I)$ denote the set of zeros of $I\subset K[x_1,x_2,\cdots ,x_n]$.

I don´t know how I should construct a set, for instance I think that it follows of apply Schwartz-Zippel Lemma, but unfortunally $A\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ can´t be divided in sets $A_1,A_2,A_3,\cdots A_n$ such that for $f\in \mathbb{R}[x,y]$ we should have
$|V(f)\cap (A_1\times A_2\times \cdots \times A_n)|\leq dm^{n-1}$.

Other idea less mathematically is think that if $f$ have degree less or equal to $2$ then
$f$ must be of the form
$$f(x,y)=ax^2+bx+c$$, $$f(x,y)=ay^2+by+c$$, $$f(x,y)=ax+by+c$$, $$f(x,y)=axy+by+cx+d$$
$$f(x,y)=Ax^2+By^2+Cx+Dy+Exy+F$$

And then consider $A=\lbrace a_i=(x_i,y_i)\mid x_i,y_i\in \mathbb{R}\rbrace$ and $i\in\lbrace 1,2,3,4,5,6 \rbrace$ and then
make $f(a_i)=0$ and show that the sistem of equations have no trival solutions for any chose of $A,B,C,D,E,F$

Comment: A bit pedantic; this is impossible unless you include the condition that $f\in \Bbb{R}[x,y]$ is nonzero. Also, are you familiar with the fact that for any five points in the plane, there is a unique conic that passes through them? (As long as no four of them are collinear)

Comment: I´m not familiar with these fact

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement clearly fails when $f$ is the zero polynomial.
I'll assume you want an $A$ which satisfies $|A \cap V(f)| \le 5$ for all non-zero polynomial with degree at most $2$.

For any $p = (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$, let $\vec{p} =(x^2,xy,y^2,x,y,1) \in \mathbb{R}^6$.

For any $f \in \mathbb{R}[x,y]$ with $\deg f \le 2$, let $B, \ldots, G$ be its coefficients. More precisely, $$f(x,y) = B x^2+ Cxy+Dy^2+Ex+Fy+G$$
Let $\vec{f} = (B,C,D,E,F,G) \in \mathbb{R}^6$.

It is easy to see $p \in V(f)$ if and only if $\vec{f}\cdot \vec{p} = 0$.

If you pick any $6$ points $p_1,\ldots,p_6$ so that corresponding $\vec{p}_1,\ldots,\vec{p}_6$ are linear independent, then $\vec{f}\cdot \vec{p}_i = 0$ for all $i$ forces $\vec{f} = \vec{0}$ which is equivalent to $f$ is the zero polynomial.

To see this, treat $\vec{f}$ and $\vec{p}_i$ as $1\times 6$ row vectors. Let $P$ be the $6\times 6$ matrix whose $i^{th}$ row is $\vec{p}_i$. It is not hard to see

$$\vec{f} P^T = (\vec{f}\cdot\vec{p}_1,\ldots,\vec{f}\cdot\vec{p}_6)$$
The condition $\vec{f}\cdot\vec{p_i} = 0$ for all $i$ is equivalent to $\vec{f} P^T = \vec{0}$. If $\vec{p}_i$ is linear independent, $P$ and hence $P^T$ will be invertible and this leads to
$\vec{f} = \vec{0} (P^T)^{-1} = \vec{0}$.

For such $6$ points, let $A = \{ p_1, \ldots, p_6 \}$. It will have the property $|A \cap V(f)| \le 5$ for all non-zero polynomial $f$ with degree at most $2$. As an example, you can choose
$$(p_1,\ldots,p_6) = (0,0),(1,0),(0,1),(-1,0),(0,-1),(1,1)$$
By brute force, you can verify $\det P = 4$, this implies
above $\vec{p}_1,\ldots,\vec{p}_6$ are linear independent and give you one example of $A$.

Comment: In the first part of you argue you use the fact that $\vec{p}_1,\cdots \vec{p}_6$ are Linearly independent, which means that of course any linearcombination $M=\sum_{i=1}^{6} \beta \vec{p}_i=0$ implies $\beta_i=0$, but you need have a linear combination of all your vectors $\vec{p}_i$ and not only $\vec{f}\vec{p}_i $ which implies that you can´t say that it forces to $\vec{f}=0$ or I don´t understand it.The second comment is the $6$ points $p_1,p_2,\cdots p_6$ are vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$ if is the case how you include it to be vectors of $\mathbb{R}^6$?

Comment: @AlanJr In $\mathbb{R}^n$, any $n$ linear independent vectors form a basis. In our case,  whenever the six $\vec{p}_i$ are linear independent, there are real numberss $\alpha_i$ such that $\vec{f} = \sum_{i=1}^6 \alpha_i \vec{p}_i$. If all $\vec{f}\cdot\vec{p}_i = 0$, then $|\vec{f}|^2 = \sum_{i=1}^6 \alpha_i \vec{f}\cdot\vec{p}_i = 0 \implies \vec{f} = 0$. For the second comment, it is a typo and I fixed that when you are writing previous comment.

Comment: Then when you write : If you pick any 6 points $p_1,p_2,\cdots p_6$ you refer to $p_1,p_2,\cdots p_6\in \mathbb{R}^6$ such that it are  linearly independent?

Comment: And when you provided an example of $A$ how you pass from $(x,y)$ points to construct your matrix $P$ which have rows vectors in $\mathbb{R}^6$?

Comment: (1) No $p_1,\cdots,p_6$ are points in $\mathbb{R}^2$. They are supposed to be chosen to make  corresponding $\vec{p}_1,\ldots,\vec{p}_6 \in \mathbb{R}^6$  linear independent .  (2) given $p_i = (x_i,y_i)$, the $i^{th}$ row of $P$ is  $\vec{p}_i = (x_i^2,x_i y_i,y_i^2,x_i,y_i,1)$ (defined in 2nd paragraph)

Comment: Thanks a lot! it clarify all and now your idea make me sense.  Good answer is pretty clear.